# Sublime text sftp stopped uploading php on save

Tags: file-upload, sublimetext2, sftp

Sublime (2) recently stopped uploading on save. It was working and suddenly it stopped. **Seems like the issue is only with php files though.**

Here's my sftp-config for reference:

```
"type": "ftp",

"save_before_upload": true,
"upload_on_save": true,
"sync_down_on_open": false,
"sync_skip_deletes": false,
"sync_same_age": true,
"confirm_downloads": false,
"confirm_sync": true,
"confirm_overwrite_newer": false,

"host": "XXX",
"user": "XXX",
"password": "XXX",
//"port": "22",

"remote_path": "/XXX/",
"ignore_regexes": [
    "\\.sublime-(project|workspace)", "sftp-config(-alt\\d?)?\\.json",
    "sftp-settings\\.json", "/venv/", "\\.svn/", "\\.hg/", "\\.git/",
    "\\.bzr", "_darcs", "CVS", "\\.DS_Store", "Thumbs\\.db", "desktop\\.ini"
],
//"file_permissions": "664",
//"dir_permissions": "775",

//"extra_list_connections": 0,

"connect_timeout": 30,
```

If I manually hit upload, everything works just fine, however the upload_on_save seems to be ignored?

Answer (score 0):

upload_on_save work only with project dir

you need to open sidebar, put sftp-config into some folder and add this folder to sidebar

then right-click to folder and choose SFTP/FTP > Browse Remote..